# How do I get directory of multiple files in multiple variables?

Tags: c#, .net

I want to read 2 excel files from the same directory and store their full paths in two different variables.

For example,

```
C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\Folder\\File1.xlsx - First value
C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\Folder\\File2.xlsx - Second value
```

I am taking a `string` array for this but it is not working.

Please help.

I have done the following:

```
string[] location = new string[2];
int i = 0;

OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();
this.openFileDialog1.Filter = "Excel|*.xlsx;*.xlxm;*.xls | All files (*.*)|*.*";
this.openFileDialog1.Multiselect = true;
this.openFileDialog1.Title = "Select Excel Files";

DialogResult dr = this.openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
if (dr == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
{
    foreach (String file in openFileDialog1.FileNames)
    {
        location[i] = Path.GetDirectoryName(file);
        i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: what part of your code is "not working" what does "not working" mean in your case?

Comment: Can you clarify "it's not working"?  What is not working?

Comment: .FileNames is already an array btw ...

Comment: `GetDirectoryName` will be the same value for all files. What do you really want?

Comment: Like I mentioned, I want the full path, including the filename. So, I already have an array but it is not entering the `foreach` loop.

Comment: 1) `openFileDialog1` and `this.openFileDialog1` are different things. 2) Try opening a file from notepad, can you select from multiple directories? Well same idea in code.

Comment: Use a folder dialog :  FolderBrowserDialog dialog = new FolderBrowserDialog();
            dialog.SelectedPath = @"c:\";
            dialog.ShowDialog();

Comment: I think you want `location[i] = file`

Comment: if you are using VisualStudio then left click on `openFileDialog1` in this line: `this.openFileDialog1.Multiselect = true;` then press F12 (this will jump to the decleration line of this object) and see where it jumps to.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing I can see wrong with your code is you are creating a local instance of `OpenFileDialog` and then trying to reference it as if it were a class member field.

```
OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();
this.openFileDialog1.Filter = "Excel|*.xlsx;*.xlxm;*.xls | All files (*.*)|*.*";
```

Get rid of `this.`

Comment: the second would be that he is storing only the directory but not " their full paths " as he wrote in the post

Comment: @MongZhu -- true, but since he already had the full path and then took the extra step of converting it to just the directory portion, I'm assuming he meant to do that.

Comment: that sounds like a valid assumption :)

Comment: So, what shall I do?

Comment: @PrimoChalice -- do what I said to do.  Get rid of all the times you use `this.` literally the word "this" and the period after it.  Remove all those.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is very risky of crashing in case user does select more than one file. I see no reason why to set the array size of "location" directly to two.
I recommend you to check the comment from Alex K. The .FileNames -property of the dialog already is an array. And getting the directory, will then be the same for all (like Crowcoder wrote).

I assume, what you need at the end is this:

```
        OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();
        openFileDialog1.Filter = "Excel|*.xlsx;*.xlxm;*.xls | All files (*.*)|*.*";
        openFileDialog1.Multiselect = true;
        openFileDialog1.Title = "Select Excel Files";

        DialogResult dr = openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
        if (dr == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
        {
             string[] location = openFileDialog1.FileNames;
             // do something
        }
```

And if in case, you need the directory, do this:

```
 string[] location = openFileDialog1.FileNames.Select(x => Path.GetDirectoryName(x)).ToArray()
```